# Undefined Reference to android::LPAPlayer::*

Tags: android, c++, stagefright

I am having great difficulty with a step in compiling CyanogenMod 11(Android 4.4) for an unsupported device based on an MSM7x27A/Snapdragon S1 platform. When I attempt to build libstagefright, I come up with an undefined reference error to functions in android::LPAPlayer::*, including the constructor. The error I get is:

```
Copying: /home/dyngar-f/android/android/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/mms-common_intermediates/noproguard.classes.jar
frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp:1282: error: undefined reference to 'android::LPAPlayer::LPAPlayer(android::sp<android::MediaPlayerBase::AudioSink> const&, bool&, android::AwesomePlayer*)'
frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp:1306: error: undefined reference to 'android::LPAPlayer::mObjectsAlive'
frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp:1882: error: undefined reference to 'android::LPAPlayer::mObjectsAlive'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit statusbuild/core/shared_library.mk:81: recipe for target '/home/dyngar-f/android/android/out/target/product/schS738c/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libstagefright_intermediates/LINKED/libstagefright.so' failed
make: *** [/home/dyngar-f/android/android/out/target/product/schS738c/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libstagefright_intermediates/LINKED/libstagefright.so] Error 1make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I have searched high and low and I found no mention of this error that leads me to a solution to this problem, and I haven't arrived at a solution myself. Here are the references to this issue I have found from others:

[Gist from CMartinBaughman](https://gist.github.com/cmartinbaughman/6143284)
[Mentioned in XDA Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2059939&page=92) on this page there is also an answer that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone guide me to a solution for this issue?

Comment: Could you please specify the version of `Android` which you are trying to compile?

Comment: I'm attempting to compile CyanogenMod 11, which corresponds to Android 4.4/KitKat. Edited question to specify version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming from the linker which is unable to find the reference to `LPAPlayer` which is actually a customization in `CyanogenMod` sources. From the latest tree, [`Android.mk` for `libstagefright`](https://github.com/NovaFusion/android_frameworks_av/blob/cm-11.0/media/libstagefright/Android.mk) is **not including** `LPAPlayer.cpp` for all platforms.

To resolve your issue, please try by adding the following files in `Android.mk` between lines 114-117

```
#New lines included
ifeq ($(call is-chipset-in-board-platform,msm7x27),true)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES += LPAPlayer.cpp
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DLEGACY_LPA -DUSE_LPA_MODE
endif

ifeq ($(call is-chipset-in-board-platform,msm7x30),true)
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES += LPAPlayer.cpp
   LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DLEGACY_LPA -DUSE_LPA_MODE
endif
```

The platform name may need to be modified to suit the actual name (Please refer to `BoardConfig.mk`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance so far. I don't have 15 Reputation on this account to upvote you for this, but it is far and away the best answer I've seen so far. I have a follow-up question though, I've been doing my modifications to the CM code by forking the original, making the edits, then expressing the edits as a patch and putting it in a "patches" folder in the device tree to be applied before building. Since this is a case where I will be adding to that patches folder, is there a better/more widely accepted way to package these types of modifications?

Comment: I haven't worked on CM yet and more of an `AOSP` guy. Typically, we merge the patch on the `git` through `gerrit`. If a patch is required to be upstreamed, then we submit a patch through the corresponding process. I am sorry I haven't got any idea on build through `patches` folder as I haven't worked on this setup earlier.

Comment: Update: With your help I got it working today, I now have CM11 working on the cheapest phone in the grocery store. As for the patches thing, I just took it for example from a similar device repository. Basically, between 'repo sync' and 'make bacon' I apply some premade patches to the CM11 code that gets it to compile for the platform. It's probably not the best way, but I don't think CM is interested in maintaining support for Snapdragon S1. If I can upstream it though, I will. If you're interested in the device tree, my github name is also cmotc and the device is schS738c. Thanks again.